# Two buttons same width android

Tags: android, android-layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bb"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/bb"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        android:text="bb" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cc"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/bb"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/cc"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        android:text="cc" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

there should be two buttons in the screen with same width in the center. but there is nothing but blank screen x.x
I'm not that new in developing android, but sometimes I miss little details which give me a lot of headache. sorry for disturbing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
android:layout_weight
```

is not applicable for `RelativeLayout`

Remove these lines and set the

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

on both of the buttons.

Answer (score 3):

Replace the `RelativeLayout` that wraps your `Buttons` with a `LinearLayout` like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bb"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/bb"
    android:drawablePadding="5dp"
    android:text="bb" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/cc"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/bb"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/cc"
    android:drawablePadding="5dp"
    android:text="cc" />

</LinearLayout>
```

`RelativeLayout` does not support `weight`.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you check prompt? You cannot use `RelativeLayout`. Change it to `LinearLayout`